# Favicon not showing on safari despite several sizes

Tags: vue.js, safari, vuejs3, favicon, nuxtjs3

i am trying to get a favicon to display on safari it works on every other browser except safari.

The application i built runs on Nuxt3 with composition api.

In the default layout i've added the following code using Nuxt components:

```html
<Head>
  <Title>{{ route.meta.title }}</Title>
  <Link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="57x57"
    href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="72x72"
    href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="76x76"
    href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="114x114"
    href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="120x120"
    href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="144x144"
    href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="152x152"
    href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="180x180"
    href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="icon"
    type="image/png"
    sizes="32x32"
    href="/faviconsfavicons/favicon-32x32.png"
  />
  <Link
    rel="icon"
    type="image/png"
    sizes="16x16"
    href="/favicons/favicon-16x16.png"
  />
  <Link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.svg" color="#000000" />
  <Link rel="manifest" href="/favicons/site.webmanifest" />
  <Link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <Meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
  <Meta name="msapplication-config" content="/favicons/browserconfig.xml" />
  <Meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
</Head>
```

After applying all this code i went to `~/Library/Safari/Favicon Cache`, deleted everything inside opened safari again to discover it still doesn't work.

I've tried everything i found on older posts regarding this subject however nothing worked and allot of it seems outdated like the mask-icon for example (even Apple doesn't use it for their website anymore). Still tried it didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try to open a private window and see it there (cache issue maybe? not sure about the directory above but a private tab is probably the best to try). Otherwise, maybe another device?

Comment: That partially worked, i got it showing in the tab but not in the bookmarks

Comment: Do you have your website hosted? I could try on my side.

Comment: Unfortunetly i am not allowed to share the link :(

Answer (score 0):

You can put the head parts in your [`nuxt.config`](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/nuxt.config):

```
head: {
  title: "Your global title",
    htmlAttrs: {
    lang: "en",
  },
  meta: [
    { charset: "utf-8" },
    { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
    {
      hid: "description",
      name: "description",
      content: "Fallback description",
    },
  ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/png", href: "/favicon.png" }],
},
```

This part is for your favicons:
`link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/png", href: "/favicon.png" }],`

Does this help?
Even if not, it's the better way to implement the links and meta data.